# sort country name with option as last

Tags: sql, sorting

i have resultset object and it containing some country names. e.g.

rs={India, Japan, USA, Options, Quatar..etc}

now i want to display Options should come last after sorting.

Comment: What have you tried?  And can you give some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to have all country names sorted, but with `Options` at the end, you can add an `ORDER BY` clause specifically for `Options`, ie

```
SELECT CountryName
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN CountryName = 'Options' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CountryName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY IF(`rs` = 'Options', 1, 0), `rs`
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option if you intend to reuse the same sort order is to create a table with two columns: varchar country and int order. Then join your results with that table and order by order.